# SASS DevTools not pointing to the variable declaration

Tags: webpack, sass, google-chrome-devtools, compass-sass, devtools

I'm using Chrome DevTools with sass files source maps. Everything works fine except one thing. I want to achieve this:

https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/2013/06/1-elem-to-source.gif[image]

1. When he clicks on "color" DevTools points to the color declaration.
2. When he clicks on "#232927" it points him to the variable declaration

Point 2. works not for me, it points always to the color declaration. Check the video here:

[enter link description here](https://www.screencast.com/t/AKtubThn5)

Is something wrong in my webpack configuration or chrome dev tools? thx

Comment: I'm not sure if this feature still exists, but are you holding <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> before clicking? That's what the keyboard symbol on the GIF is instructing you to do.

Comment: Yes i tried that and it didn't helped.